# hcmap R character error with France map

Tags: r, highcharts

I made a Choropleth map of France but I would like to change the text shown for each region.

Till now, with this code

```
hcmap("countries/fr/custom/fr-all-mainland", data = data, value = "number",
+       joinBy = c("hc-key", "region"), name = "Data",
+       dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.name}'),
+       borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1)
```

I have this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS4zo.png)

Is there a way to change the name of the region for the number used to make the cloropleph ?
Example : instead of "Picardie", I would like to have "16" in the map

Comment: I guess there is that value (16) in your `data`, in that case try using `format = '{point.the_name_of_the_var_which_contain_your_label}'`

Comment: `{point.value}` or `{point.y}` should be fine.

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks ! Other question : would you know how to fix the character problems in the region names that you see in the picture, and add a black border between each region ? I guess I should create another post for this so if necessary, just tell me

Comment: edit : I found the way for the borders : borderColor = "black", borderWidth = 0.5   but I don't know yet how to fix the character problem